# How can I convert the following Java code to Node.js?

Tags: java, node.js, binary

I have the following Java code:

```
int data = Float.floatToIntBits(4.2);
sendCommand(0x50, data);

public void sendCommand(byte type, int data) {
  byte[] cmd = new byte[FRAME_LENGTH];
  cmd[0] = type;
  cmd[1] = (byte)(data);
  cmd[2] = (byte)(data >>> 8);
  cmd[3] = (byte)(data >>> 16);
  cmd[4] = (byte)(data >>> 24);
  printFrame(cmd);
}
```

I need to convert it to Node.js. I first thought to use the Buffer module, but I have no idea how to interpret the above code. Here is my attempt, but it doesn't seem correct:

```
const type = 0x50;
const data = 25;
function sendCommand(type, data) {
  const buff = Buffer.from([type, data, data >>> 8, data >>> 16, data >>> 24]);
  console.debug(buff);
}
```

Can you advise?

Comment: What makes you say it doesn't seem correct?

Comment: @aymericbeaumet, thanks for your question. It made me think I was correct. All I had to do is just to set the `type` value as a **string**

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty close...
Since JavaScript converts hex data to integer on the fly, we need to set them as a string. So, instead of:

```
const type = 0x50;
```

We have to use:

```
const type = '0x50';
```

So, the equivalent of the Node.js program to the Java program posted in the question would be:

```
const type = '0x50';
const data = 25;
sendCommand(type, data);

function sendCommand(type, data) {
  const buff = Buffer.from([type, data, data >>> 8, data >>> 16, data >>> 24]);
  console.debug(buff);
}
```